# css selector, parent element with child element (and its children)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Can anyone explain why is this not working? on *div>**ol**:first-child* ?

```
div>ul:first-child
{
    background:yellow;
}
```

The style on top works.. for ul. hi-lighting it. If I change >ul to >ol.. nothing happens

```
<div>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mFMuq/

Comment: the `ol` isn't the first child of the `div`, which is why it doesn't get highlighted.. I suggest reading this http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child

Comment: @billyonecan +1 for using w3.org as opposed to *looks left* *looks right* w3schools.com like the first answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From w3schools.com [first-child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp):

```
The :first-child selector is used to select the specified selector, only if it is the first child of its parent.
```

The ol isn't the first child of it's parent, it doesn't actually matter that it's the first ol of it's parent.  If you swap the ol and ul around then the ol works but the ul doesn't.

If you want to target the first ol then use the :first-of-type selector. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ReyGu)

Comment: ok, how can I make it hi-light my FIRST ol, for example I have two OLs http://jsfiddle.net/mFMuq/9/

Comment: w3schools is a wrong and misleading site. You shouldn't use it as reference for any sort of language. For PHP, there's the [PHP Manual](http://php.net), for JavaScript, there's [Mozilla Developer Network (or MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/). See http://w3fools.com to further understand why you should never use w3schools.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep that in mind. I wondered why I was getting so many downvotes for a correct answer :)